# Method to prevent duplicates of the connected entities

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I have a custom entity that is linked to a Shopware entity, for example, `cms_page`. This custom entity has a reference to `cms_page` in the database. When a `cms_page` is duplicated, my custom entity is also duplicated, which I want to prevent.
Previously, I listened to the `CmsPageEvents::PAGE_WRITTEN_EVENT` event and used `event->getEvents()` to find the connected events to my custom entity. However, I noticed that the collection is now empty.
Is there another method to prevent duplicates of the connected entities? Additionally, is there a way to detect when an entity was duplicated?